# What are the origins/geneology of various mleccha tribes?

Tags: puranas, manu-smriti

> “Those various men of Kṣatriya birth — Dramiḻas, Kaliṅgas, Pulindas,
>   Uśīnaras, Kaulas, Sarpas, and Māhiṣakas — have reached the level of
>   Śūdras because no Brahmins are seen among them.” mahabharata 3.33.19-21
>
> “By neglecting rites and because no Brahmins are seen among them,
>   these men of Kṣatriya birth have gradually reached in the world the
>   level of Śūdras — Puṇḍrakas, Coḍas, Draviḍas, Kāmbojas, Yavanas,
>   Śakas, Pāradas, Pahlavas, Cīnas, Kirātas, and Daradas.” [manu smriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201774.html)

We do know that some of these were progeneted from lunar dynasty, are geneologies of all these tribes given in puranas? How did they originate did they originate from different divinities?